# When printing from command line how to know what was the default font and font size is being used to print

Tags: linux, printing, cups, lpr

I am printing from a text file. I would like to know what was the default font and font size is being used. Is there a way to find out?

```
lp template.html -d TVS_MSP-250CH-custom
```

Answer (score 0):

The post
[How to change font size in msp240 star tvs printer](https://www.fixya.com/support/t25064285-change_font_size_in_msp240_star_tvs)
has the following procedure.

The printer model is pretty close to yours.

> 1. Press the "Menu" button on the device's keypad to access the menu.
> 2. Press "Menu" again to enter the "Configuration options" page.
> 3. Press the "Down" button to select "Font Options."
> 4. Press the "Down" button and select "Size." Press the "Right" button to raise the size by one bullet point, the "Left" button to lower it.
> 5. Repeat this until you have reached your desired size, then press "Menu" again to exit the menu and commit your changes.

Comment: I am not asking for how to changes I want to know what was the default font and font size it used when running from command line

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have much a choice beside the font that you choose above.